# How to Set, Postback, and retrieve hiddenField value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net-2010

I have a asp gridview with 3 input type"text" fields in it. Those fields get populated by a query and each row has the option to EDIT. When i click the edit button in the gridview, it postback but the value of the input fields are of course lost during the post back :(. So i wanted to store the values into a hiddenfield and then use it on server side. These are within an edititemtemplate tag.

```
<input type="text" id="editBeginDate" class="DatePicker" runat="server" readonly="readonly" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="ehBeginDate" runat="server" />
```

I am setting the value of the hidden field at document.ready via jquery using this...

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("[id$=ehBeginDate]").val();
    });
```

What is happening when the user clicks edit, it sets the row to edit mode but the value in these 3 input fields is set to empty because it gets "lost" some where in the post back. My plan is to retrieve the hiddenfield value (and take over the world! jk)  and then do .findcontrol("inputfield") and set its text = hiddenfield.value... thoughts??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `OnRowEditing`attribute when you create the grid, there is a line you can put in the event that may help you out.

Try using this as the first line of your row editing.  Then swap out the cells for the text boxes however you want by getting the values and plugging them in. The ASP Gridview has a default edit built into it, but I don't think it hangs on to your values before displaying the textboxes.

***Line to add to the edit event***

`e.Cancel = true;`

Answer (score 0):

I use that event and i am doing this to find the control in the grid and then pull the value but the issue is this...When i hit this event the values are already gone from the previous stated input controls....ideas?

```
 Dim txtBeginDate As System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText = gv.Rows(e.NewEditIndex).FindControl("editBeginDate")
```

Comment: These values use to be retained throughout the editing event and on population of the grid. They stopped going through when i added a jquery datepicker to the input controls. The datepicker code is simply this